# Quoted text aligned outside left edge of question for particular content

Tags: bug, design, blockquote

I just discovered a weird formatting bug with quoted text where the quoted text is left aligned way outside the left margin of the question (and possibly answer too).

Here's the bug in its shortest reproducible form:

> 1. 0

Here's a screenshot for posterity to capture what it looked like before the bug was fixed:

[image: screenshot]

Browser: Chrome
Machine: Macbook

Comment: Can reproduce in Firefox `58.0b10 (32-bit)`, Windows 7

Comment: iOS app have buggy rendering also. See the pictures from [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304472/339911).