# Open post in full screen by tapping on the title

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Currently if you open the site from the iOS app in landscape mode you will see two columns (except navigation bar): list of questions and the selected question itself:

> [image: 2 cols]

If you make an edit and submit it you will see the post in “full screen” (e.i. no column with the questions list):

> [image: 1 col]

Tapping the “<“ symbol will return you to previous view with two columns.

Is it possible to add an ability by tapping on the post title from the first picture switch to the view like on the second picture? This ability could help to use screen space more efficiently if you digging on the post.